# Is it possible to overload "array assignment" for a custom struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, struct, overloading

It's a pretty straightforward question, if I want to specify the exact values of a new array in C# all I do is:

```
foo[] arr = {10, 15, 24};
```

Is it possible to do this with custom structs?

e.g.

```
public struct Vec3
{
    float[] MyVals;
    public float this[int a]
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        } 
    }
}

public class MainRoutine
{
    public static Vec3 SuperVector = {2, 5, 6};

    .....

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) you can do this:

```
public struct Vec3
{
    private float[] MyVals;

    public float this[int a]
    {
        get { return MyVals[a]; }
        set { MyVals[a] = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator float[](Vec3 vec)
    {
        return vec.MyVals;
    }
     public static implicit operator Vec3(float[] values)
     {
         var v = new Vec3();
         v.MyVals = values;
         return v;
     }
}

 public static Vec3 SuperVector = new[] { 2f, 5f, 6f };
```

ofcourse `new[]` is shorthand for `new float[]`, this not exactly what you want but I think it is nearest. this array initializer syntax `int[] arr = { 2, 3, 4 }` can be used only for arrays, so it's not possible in any way.

Comment: last Line `public static Vec3 SuperVector = new Vec3[] { 2f, 5f, 6f };`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal it won't compile

Comment: I think I like yours the most.  I didn't realize that an array of floats could be considered an "operator."  Learn new tricks every day.

Comment: I get it now, it's just a casting overload.  I've done that before but I guess I just never really thought of casting overloading an array, just primitive types.  Than ks!  I suppose this should have been obvious.  Now I've included casting overloads to directly assign an enumeration (e.g. Vec3 Vector = UnitVec.x).  I guess I didn't really get the full power of casting overloads until your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not like that. C# doesn't know what each of those values should map to (imagine you had a more complicated struct). In an array (or any other collection, incidentally), its obvious; the provided elements just make up the array.

However, you can do:

```
public static Vec3 SuperVector = new Vec3
{
   MyVals = new float[]{2, 5, 6}
}
```

If you make `MyVals` a public property. Of course, you can also pass the elements in on the constructor (or the array).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for more information on object initializers.

Comment: Thanks, though I do hate exposing the underlying primitives of structures.  I suppose I'm the only one working with it.

Answer (score 1):

Did something like this

```
class Program
{
    public static Vec3 SuperVector = new Vec3 { 2, 5, 6 };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SuperVector[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(SuperVector[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(SuperVector[2]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public struct Vec3: IEnumerable
{
    List<float> MyVals;

    public float this[int a]
    {
        get
        {
            return MyVals[a];
        }
        set
        {
            InitiailaizeMyValIfEmpty();
            MyVals[a] = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(float f)
    {
        InitiailaizeMyValIfEmpty();
        MyVals.Add(f);
    }

    private void InitiailaizeMyValIfEmpty()
    {
        if (MyVals == null)
            MyVals = new List<float>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't experimented with extending IEnumerable... I don't even really understand what it is...  I suppose I will have to look into that.  If you use a structure and extend something does it increase the overhead or does it just provide access to the extended class' methods?  I'm trying to create as optimized 3d Perlin noise as possible so this new vec class needs to be as optimized as possible.